# Compare and trim binary/unicoded string to normal string?

Tags: php, mysql, regex, binary, trim

I am using below mysql query to check which records vary from the trimmed value

```
SELECT id,
   BINARY(username) AS binary_username,
   TRIM(username) AS trim_username
FROM table.
```

Above query returns binary value and trimmed value as shown below.

**Result of mysql query:**

[image: mysql-query-result]

***Highlighted values in above image show that binary value vary from trimmed value.***

I tried below 2 things:

- calculating length of both binary and trimmed column but it is same `LENGTH(binary_username) != LENGTH(trim_username)`.
- equating them directly `binary_username != trim_username`.

but both of them are returning empty records.

**How can I fetch these highlighted entries using mysql?**

**Edit 1:** I have added HEX value in the query result

```
SELECT id,
   BINARY(username) AS binary_username,
   TRIM(username) AS trim_username,
   HEX(username) AS hex_username
FROM TABLE
```

[image: query-result]

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Showing `hex(username)` might help.

Comment: No, that didn't worked

Comment: what do you mean "it didn't work"? The output of `hex(trim(username))` for 196447 was `546F617374` then?

Comment: Try `where username != trim(username)`. I suspect you have strange whitespace on the end of the username

Comment: Just get HEX(username); I suspect it was double-encoded!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid storing, trimming, etc, the trailing zeros, use `VARBINARY` instead of `BINARY`.  Why, pray tell, are you using BINARY for text strings??

Please do `SELECT HEX(username) FROM ...` so we can further diagnose the problem.  That screenshot is suspect -- we don't know what the client did to "fix" the output.

Well, none of those are encoded in UTF-8, nor anything else that I recognize.  The 'bad' characters (02, 04, 0c 17), are all "control codes" in virtually all encodings.  ("Unicode" is not an encoding method, so it is not relevant.)

Would you like a REGEXP that tests for control codes?

In PHP, json_encode has an option for `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`.  See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

But that generates `\u1234` type text.

When storing binary data into MySQL, use the binding or escaping mechanism in PDO or mysqli.

Comment: I'm not using `BINARY` for text strings, I'm using `VARCHAR` only. Someone was passing in unicoded strings which I need to identify and remove. Also I need to restrict any further user from passing these unicoded strings.

Comment: @AnkitJindal - I added to my answer.

Comment: I'm getting inputs like `20\u00042I\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000`, `\ufffd\u001ex\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd~\ufffd\ufffdM4\ufffdM4\ufffd` which I need to restrict. What is a good way to handle all such cases?

Comment: Coming from JSON?  See the options.

Comment: Which options are you referring in your comment?

Comment: @AnkitJindal - I added some more to my Answer.  (But I still don't see where your garbage is really coming from.